# Adding chat functionality to website

Tags: javascript, vb.net, xmlhttprequest, chat, polling

I've been able to add chat functionality to my website but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it. This is the current structure of the chat:

HTML page with javascript functions:

```
sendChat(elmnt) {
 var result = XHR("http_sendChat.aspx","POST",0,elmnt); //xmlhttprequest to send chat message by posting elmnt string to page. 0 used for not polling
}

getChat() {
 var result = XHR("http_getChat.aspx","GET",50,""); //polls page every 50ms to get new chat messages
 addMessageElmnt(result); //update chat window with new messages
}
```

On the server side in vb.net http_sendChat.aspx:

```
Application.Lock
Application("chat") = Application("chat") & Request.Form("message") //Global application object stores chat log
Application.Unlock
```

On the server side in vb.net http_getChat.aspx:

```
Dim chatTemp
chatTemp = Mid(Application("chat"),Session("chatIndex")) //fetches whatever chat data hasn't been fetched yet
Session("chatIndex") = Session("chatIndex") + Len(chatTemp) //set index to last read position
Response.Write(chatTemp)
```

There is some more code that mostly checks to make sure the users account is activated and such but as far as the chat goes, is there a better way to do this? I ask because its fairly slow when there are like 100 people logged in and using the chat.

Comment: Have you considered using [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)?

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use some kind of pre built chat library or service?

Comment: Give a try to socket.io (They have a chat example to get started) i dont know if there is a backend driver for .net you should investigate that http://socket.io/

Comment: Are websockets supported by all modern browsers? If there are hundreds of people connected would it be any faster? I feel like writing the same string to 100 sockets is slower than writing it to one application variable that 100 users read from.

I'm not familiar with any pre built chat libraries or services, if you know of any that would be more efficient than what I'm using now I would appreciate that.

This is my first time creating any kind of web chat so I'm trying to tackle it however I can.